# ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY nick ORDER BY p_time) in R

Tags: r, postgresql

having

```
x=data.frame(nick=c('a','a','b','b','b','c'), p_time=1:6)
  nick p_time
1    a      1
2    a      2
3    b      3
4    b      4
5    b      5
6    c      6
```

how can i get this：

```
  nick p_time flag
1    a      1    1
2    a      2    2
3    b      3    1
4    b      4    2
5    b      5    3
6    c      6    1
```

i used pgsql `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY nick ORDER BY p_time)` to get it,but now need to use R only.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want to generate a "serial number" of sorts by group, where your groups are the "nick" column. If that's the case, you can just use `ave` and `seq_along` within `within`:

```
within(x, {
  flag <- ave(as.character(nick), nick, FUN = seq_along)
})
#   nick p_time flag
# 1    a      1    1
# 2    a      2    2
# 3    b      3    1
# 4    b      4    2
# 5    b      5    3
# 6    c      6    1
```

Comment: ave+seq_along is what i need

Comment: Watch out for the `ORDER BY p_time` part, though.

Comment: yep, that's sample data, before generating the regular sequences, i had done `x[order(nick, p_time), ]`

Answer (score 3):

Try dplyr::row_number() function

```
x %>% 
  group_by(nick) %>%
  mutate(flag = row_number())

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups: nick [3]
  nick  p_time  flag
  <fct>  <int> <int>
1 a          1     1
2 a          2     2
3 b          3     1
4 b          4     2
5 b          5     3
6 c          6     1
```

more information [here](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/ranking.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
x$flag<-as.vector(unlist(tapply(x$p_time,x$nick,FUN=function(x){1:length(x)})));
```